# How to Change output text with selective options in html tag

Tags: html

I have this code :

```
<ul class="quick-contact">
    <li class="phone"><strong>Sales: </strong>0987 989898</li>
    <li class="email"><strong>Email: </strong><a href="#" title="Sample link">info@yourdomain.com</a></li>
    <li class="sites"><strong>Sites: </strong><select class="inputbox"><option>USA</option><option>UK</option><option>France</option><option>Japan</option><option>South Africa</option></select></li>
</ul>
```

I want sales number change with each options selected.
If someone has any ideas I really appreciate all answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make use of Javascript to achieve this functionality.

**Working Snippet:**

`// comments inline`

```js
var salesNumbers = {  // store all phone numbers in an object here
  'USA': '123 123',   // you can easily add/remove/modify the country/numbers here
  'UK': '456 456',
  'France': '789 789',
  'Japan': '111 222',
  'South Africa': '333 444'
}

function updateSalesNumber(){  // this will be called when dropdown value will be changed
  var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputbox"); 
  
  // get the selected option
  var selectedOption = inputBox.options[inputBox.selectedIndex].value;
  
  // update the number on the webpage
  document.getElementById("sales-number").innerHTML = salesNumbers[selectedOption];
}
```

```html
<ul class="quick-contact">
    <li class="phone"><strong>Sales: </strong><span id="sales-number">0987 989898</span></li>
    <li class="email"><strong>Email: </strong><a href="#" title="Sample link">info@yourdomain.com</a></li>
    <li class="sites"><strong>Sites: </strong>
      <select id="inputbox" onchange="updateSalesNumber()">
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="USA">UK</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
      </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you but I want use multi languages with different encoding types and using options as variable names are not really suited for me.is there any way to fix it or make it possible to use bridge variables to make it right ?

Comment: @user2737309 You can achieve that by setting `value` attribute for every option and matching it with the properties in the `object` that I mentioned in the beginning. I have updated my code above with this change. With this change it doesnt matter in what language the text is shown in the options, the value will always be the same. Let me know if that answers your question. :)

Comment: Do you know how can I join this jquery and joomla custom html module ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript or jQuery to do what you want to do. This is the only way to manipulate values in the DOM.

Different people will give you different answers. But here is one simple option using jQuery.

I have written a jQuery example but if you need a pure javascript one let me know.

Basically you need a value on all your options which contains the phone number that corresponds to it. (e.g USA and a value for it's phone number).

When the select box is changed it updates the sale number. I have added an extra span with a class to make it easier to update.

http://jsfiddle.net/williamtdavies/6621wd1j/

```
<ul class="quick-contact">
    <li class="phone"><strong>Sales: </strong><span class="phone__number">0987 989898</span></li>
    <li class="email"><strong>Email: </strong><a href="#" title="Sample link">info@yourdomain.com</a></li>
    <li class="sites"><strong>Sites: </strong><select class="inputbox"><option value="123">USA</option><option value="456">UK</option><option value="789">France</option><option value="101112">Japan</option><option value="131415">South Africa</option></select></li>
</ul>

// Function to update the sales phone number
function changePhoneNumber(phoneNumber){ 
   // Writes HTML into the span with class "phone__number"
   $('.phone__number').html(phoneNumber);
}

// Change event calls the function to update the sales number
// Passes the new value after change into the function
$('.inputbox').on('change', function(){
   var phoneNumber = $(this).val();
    changePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
});

// Calls the function on load in case the select box selection has remained from a previous change
$(document).ready(function(){
    changePhoneNumber($('.inputbox').val());
});
```

Comment: First of all thank you,actually I have some limitations with using jQuery I want to post this html code in joomla custom html module and there I don't know if I could use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

***Include jQuery and use below js***

```
var inputBox = $(".inputbox"),
      countryNumber = $('#country-number');

console.log(inputBox.length);

function updateSalesNumber(){
  countryNumber.text(inputBox.val());
}

inputBox.on('change', function(){
    updateSalesNumber();
})
```

***Use below html...***

```
<ul class="quick-contact">
    <li class="phone"><strong>Sales: </strong> <span id="country-number">0987 989898</span></li>
    <li class="email"><strong>Email: </strong><a href="#" title="Sample link">info@yourdomain.com</a></li>
    <li class="sites"><strong>Sites: </strong><select class="inputbox"><option value="111111">USA</option><option value="222222">UK</option><option value="333333">France</option><option value="444444">Japan</option><option value="555555">South Africa</option></select></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: dear friend I'm new at binding jquery and html,as I said I want to use this code in my joomla custom module and it only allows to use html but for using jquery include I believe there is a way and I just don't know it,I must search more and learn more . . .